# Undefined behavior caused by not proper memory reusing

Tags: c++, constructor

The standard cite the following example (3.8/7 N3797):

```
struct C 
{
    int i;
    void f();
    const C& operator=( const C& );
};

const C& C::operator=( const C& other) 
{
    if ( this != &other ) 
    {
        this->~C(); // lifetime of *this ends
        new (this) C(other); // new object of type C created
        f(); // well-defined
    }
return *this;
}

C c1;
C c2;
c1 = c2; // well-defined
c1.f(); // well-defined; c1 refers to a new object of type C
```

Is there UB if we implement `operator=` as follows:

```
const C& C::operator=( const C& other) 
{
    if ( this != &other ) 
    {                        // Note that there is no more explcicitly destructor call,
                             // since at the time of memory reusing the lifetime of 
                             // this is still going on
        new (this) C(other); // new object of type C created
        f(); // well-defined
    }
return *this;
}
```

Relevant quote is:

> If, **after the lifetime** of an object **has ended** and **before the storage**
>   which the object occupied **is reused or released**, a new object is
>   created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a
>   pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred
>   to the original object, or the name of the original object will
>   automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the
>   new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object

There is no rule for: **"Creating a new object at the storage location than an object occupies"**. 
Meanwhile, we have a suitable rule for a `const` object. And it is clear:

Section 3.8/9:

> **Creating a new object at the storage location that a const object** with
>   static, thread, or automatic storage duration **occupies** or, at the
>   storage location that such a const object used to occupy before its
>   lifetime ended results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant rule is this:

> **3.8/4** A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies or by
>   explicitly calling the destructor for an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor. For an object
>   of a class type with a non-trivial destructor, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly
>   before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released; however, if there is no explicit call to
>   the destructor or if a *delete-expression* (5.3.5) is not used to release the storage, the destructor shall not be
>   implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined
>   behavior.

Your example, as written, is legal because `C` has a trivial destructor.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. But I've one more question. When we reusing memory, the lifetime is still going on. 3.8/7 doesn't cover that case, right?

Comment: 3.8/7 applies to the case when the lefitime has ended. It confuses me.

Comment: `**3.8/1** The lifetime of an object of type T ends when ... the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.`

Comment: I know it. But _after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created [...]_ means that the lifetime has already ended **before** (I.e. earlier that we're starting to create a new object) the time we're creating a new object.

Comment: This gap between "lifetime has ended" and "storage is reused or released" can exist only if the lifetime was ended by means of explicitly calling the destructor.